# How to add both onclick and href both a in a button of a React page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick, href

I have a button element in React page. With onclick event I called a function from my context. Now I want to add a href in that button.

Here is my code:

```
{ categoryData.map((item,index)=>{
            return(
                  
                <button className="dropdown-item"  to={/articles/${item}} onClick={updateFilterValue} key={index}  name="category" value={item}>{ item }</button>
                )
})}
```

This is my updateFilterValue function:

```
const updateFilterValue = (event) => {
        let name = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;
    
        return dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_FILTERS_VALUE", payload: { name, value } });
      };
```

Basically onclick will pass the name and value attribute to updateFilterValue function. I am getting this updateFilterValue from my context.  Now at the  same time I want to redirect to `/articles/${item}` route. How to do that?

Comment: Buttons don't have href. Consider using an [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox but I have to pass name and value attribute in updateFilterValue function . how to do that with anchor tag? how to set name and value attribute in anchor tag? please tell.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the route with the item on click, you can use the **Navigate** element of the react-router dom you can simple have this inside your function.

You can refer here for Navigate [docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate)

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
{ categoryData.map((item,index)=>{
     return(
           <button className="dropdown-item"
    onClick={()=>
    {
      updateFilterValue(name,value)
      <Navigate to=`/articles/${item}` replace={true} />
    } 
    key={index}  name="category" value={item}>{ item }</button>
    )
})
}
```

Comment: it is saying unexpected use of  name and value undefined . I want to pass name="category" value={item} to updateFilterValue(name,value) function

Comment: replace name and value with what you want to pass into the function

Comment: it will be button's name and value attribute. I don't know how to pass it.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this depending on your requirement.

**First Method**

```
import React from 'react';

const MyButton = () => {
const handleClick = () => {
// Write your onClick logic here
console.log('Button clicked');

// Navigate to a new page using window.location.href
window.location.href = 'https://example.com';
};

return (
<button onClick={handleClick}>
  Click me
</button>
);
};

export default MyButton;
```

and the **Second Method** will be:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyButtonLink = () => {
return (
<Link to="/new-page">
  <button onClick={()=> alert('on Click working')}>
    Click me
  </button>
</Link>
);
};

export default MyButtonLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `updateFilterValue` function, you can set `window.location.href = "/articles/${item}"` so that after the code of your function you get redirected to that route.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by Without using any Routing Libraby

- You Just need to add one anchor tag in Button To perform OnClick and Href.
  Just Add `<a href="/your-RouteAddress">{item}</a>`

Your Code Look Like :-

```
{
categoryData.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <button className="dropdown-item" onClick = { updateFilterValue } key = { index } name = "category"
    value = { item } >
  <a href="/articles/${item}">{item}</a>
    </button >
)
 })}
```

- You Also Can Use Link to achieve this By Using Link Tag.
  You Need to Import Link Tag

  import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

And Your Code Will be

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
{ categoryData.map((item,index)=>{
return(
    <button className="dropdown-item" onClick={updateFilterValue} key={index} name="category"
    value={item}>
    <Link to="/articles/${item}">{ item }</Link>
    </button>
)
})}
```